# ActionScript 3 - dragging only on X-axis not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, axis, drag

I have a MovieClip called 'greenBar'. This is my code:

```
var yPoint:Number = greenBar.y;

// MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE
greenBar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, _mouseMove);

function _mouseMove(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    if (evt.currentTarget.y != yPoint) {
        evt.currentTarget.y = yPoint;
    }
}

// dragging
greenBar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, _mouseDown);

function _mouseDown(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    evt.currentTarget.startDrag();
    evt.currentTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
}

// dropping
function _mouseUp(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    evt.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    evt.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, _mouseUp);
}
```

This doesn't work, I can still drag greenBar anywhere I want on the y-axis. I also tried adding a MouseEvent to the stage like so:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, _mouseMove);
```

but it gives an error saying that:

```
Error: Error #2071: The Stage class does not implement this property or method.
```

.How do I make it so that greenBar can only be dragged across the x-axis and not the y-axis?

Note: I am using ActionScript 3 and Flash CS5.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the best code but it is an option to accomplish what you need to do.

```
var drag:Boolean = false;
greenBar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
greenBar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateGreenBar);

function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    drag = true;
}
function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    drag = false;
}
function updateGreenBar(event:Event):void
{
    if(drag)
    {
        greenBar.x = mouseX;
    }
}
```